# How to Reinstall Visual Studio Package from web installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-package

Im getting error when ever i add new javascript file , typescript file in visual studio 2015 community edition.

[image]

Upon researching , this issue fix by installing the following package from ISO file available as :

x:\packages\JavaScript_LanguageService\JavaScript_LanguageService.msi

I dont have ISO File , how to re install this package **from Visual Studio Web installer** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont need to reinstall visual studio 2015 for solve this problem

now you can download this package on the folow link,i uploaded JavaScript_LanguageService package for you to solve this error.

[JavaScript_LanguageService](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=52599612846873764248)

Comment: is there any way ? to install some specific via web installer ?